# Create an Rx.Subject using Subject.create that allows onNext without subscription

Tags: rxjs

When creating an `Rx.Subject` using `Subject.create(observer, observable)`, the `Subject` is so lazy. When I try to use `subject.onNext` without having a subscription, it doesn't pass messages on. If I `subject.subscribe()` first, I can use `onNext` immediately after.

Let's say I have an `Observer`, created like so:

```
function createObserver(socket) {
  return Observer.create(msg => {
    socket.send(msg);
  }, err => {
    console.error(err);
  }, () => {
    socket.removeAllListeners();
    socket.close();
  });
}
```

Then, I create an Observable that accepts messages:

```
function createObservable(socket) {
  return Observable.fromEvent(socket, 'message')
                   .map(msg => {
                     // Trim out unnecessary data for subscribers
                     delete msg.blobs;
                     // Deep freeze the message
                     Object.freeze(msg);
                     return msg;
                   })
                   .publish()
                   .refCount();
}
```

The subject is created using these two functions.

```
observer = createObserver(socket);
observable = createObservable(socket);
subject = Subject.create(observer, observable);
```

With this setup, I'm not able to `subject.onNext` immediately (even if I don't care about subscribing). Is this by design? What's a good workaround?

These are actually TCP sockets, which is why I haven't relied on the super slick websocket subjects.

Comment: Could you be a little more descriptive, perhaps with a code example? Doesn't pass messages onto where? What are you trying to accomplish with the `Subject.create()` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The basic solution, caching nexts before subscription with ReplaySubject:

I think all you wanted to do is use a `ReplaySubject` as your observer.

```js
const { Observable, Subject, ReplaySubject } = Rx;

const replay = new ReplaySubject();

const observable = Observable.create(observer => {
  replay.subscribe(observer);
});

const mySubject = Subject.create(replay, observable);


mySubject.onNext(1);
mySubject.onNext(2);
mySubject.onNext(3);

mySubject.subscribe(x => console.log(x));

mySubject.onNext(4);
mySubject.onNext(5);
```

Results in:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

---

#### A socket implementation (example, don't use)

... but if you're looking at doing a Socket implementation, it gets a lot more complicated. Here is a working socket implementation, **but I don't recommend you use it**. Rather, I'd suggest that you use one of the community supported implementations either in [rxjs-dom](http://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM) (if you're an RxJS 4 or lower) or as part of [RxJS 5](http://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS), both of which I've helped work on.

```js
function createSocketSubject(url) {
  let replay = new ReplaySubject();
  let socket;

  const observable = Observable.create(observer => {
    socket = new WebSocket(url);

    socket.onmessage = (e) => {
      observer.onNext(e);
    };

    socket.onerror = (e) => {
      observer.onError(e);
    };

    socket.onclose = (e) => {
      if (e.wasClean) {
        observer.onCompleted();
      } else {
        observer.onError(e);
      }
    }

    let sub;
    socket.onopen = () => {
      sub = replay.subscribe(x => socket.send(x));      
    };
    return () => {
      socket && socket.readyState === 1 && socket.close();
      sub && sub.dispose();
    }
  });

  return Subject.create(replay, observable);
}

const socket = createSocketSubject('ws://echo.websocket.org');

socket.onNext('one');
socket.onNext('two');
socket.subscribe(x => console.log('response: ' + x.data));
socket.onNext('three');
socket.onNext('four');
```

[Here's the obligatory JsBin](http://jsbin.com/lihuwufiwo/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: Love your work Ben! I'm looking forward to RxJS 5. This is actually a ZeroMQ socket, server side (which has roughly the same interface as a TCP socket). I trimmed some of those specifics out of here. Actual code base: https://github.com/nteract/enchannel-zmq-backend

Comment: Thanks! :) So yeah, same basic principles apply, really. Things to remember though: If you want your Subject to be "reusable" or "resubscribable", you'll need to either protect that `replay` subject from `onComplete` or `onError` calls, or you'll need to recycle it during those events. Most likely you'll want to protect it. Once a subject is unsubscribed, it's done, and you'll need to recreate it.

Whenever you're ready to move it to RxJS 5, ping us in an issue.

Comment: This project started last week (well, we've been using zmq for sometime - observables are new to us), so we could reasonably switch to RxJS 5. Figured we'd wait until your release, though your response here + https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QhjALubBQPg tempt me. I was worried that I'd end up debugging the new module instead of our app if adopting too early.

Comment: Now that people are ending up at this question frequently (~1000 views), I'm tempted to update it with how we _now_ do this, which is to wrap the sending in once the observable is subscribed to: https://github.com/nteract/nteract/blob/a350399e8eaaefe33da3cea50d4ea1c82013fed7/src/notebook/epics/execute.js#L245-L250 It feels like a better pattern for most use cases (even though sometimes we want to be able to send without an explicit subscription).